# Кто составляет ТЗ?

Tags: документация

В организации есть **аналитик**. Он соглашается составить документ с описанием требований от заказчика. Но не хочет писать ТЗ для **программиста**.

Требования к ТЗ - составить таблицу, где будет описаны типы полей, формат ввода, видимость на этапах, тексты уведомлений и логику изменения данных по каким-то событиям. **Аналитик** хорошо знает возможности системы (речь о SharePoint).

**Аналитик** сообщает что составлять ТЗ должен **программист**. Я этот **программист**. И по-моему что-то пошло не так.

Comment: что написано у вас в должностных инструкциях, то вы и обязаны делать

Comment: Я понимаю, что Бизнес-аналитик собирает требования, а Системный аналитик адаптирует их для технического персонала. Верно ли отдавать роль Системной аналитики разработчику ПО? Организация, к слову, не маленькая. Т.е. не веб-студия из 5 человек, где совмещение ролей неизбежно.

Comment: бывает и программиcту делегируют такую почётную обязанность. может просто поговорить с ПМ?

Comment: Так же добавлю, речь идёт о разработке внутри компании, в рамках одного юридического лица.

Comment: @Alexander Ulmaskulov  Очевидно, что сам себе никто на работе технические задания не составляет. Техническое задание - это то, что должно быть предоставлено программисту.

Comment: Классный вопрос -- Вам [во флудильню](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23460/ru-so) (расскажем много забавных историй на тему составления и утрясания ТЗ с заказчиком)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ТЗ - это расшифровывается как техническое **задание**. То есть это задание от одного субъекта другому, от начальника - подчиненному, от заказчика - исполнителю и т.д.  Программист - это звено в производственном процессе, который должен получить задание, прежде чем что-то делать.  Если программист пишет сам себе задания, то это означает, что он исключен из производственного процесса, то есть не является участником производственного процесса, а является самостоятельной единицей внешней по отношению к производственному процессу.

Задача аналитика - проанализировать производственный процесс и на основе своего анализа выдать технические задания или рекомендации, если он сам не уполномочен выдавать технические задания, а, допустим, это делает другой уполномоченный сотрудник.

Описание требований от заказчика - это работа секретаря, а не аналитика.

Для аналитика требования заказчика - это всего лишь **входные данные**, на основе которых он должен выдать **выходные данные**, которыми являются технические задания. Грубо говоря работа аналитика заключается в следующем. Он должен указать: вот - что требует заказчик, и вот - что надо сделать.

А для программиста **ТЗ - это входные данные**, а **программа - это выходные данные**.

В противном случае программисту придется дублировать аналитика. А зачем тогда такой аналитик нужен?!

Фактически, в этом случае аналитик снимает с себя всякую ответственность за свою работу, так как если конечный продукт не будет устраивать заказчика, то аналитик просто скажет, что это вы написали неправильно ТЗ. То есть он полностью обрубил с вами обратную связь и тем самым, подымаясь по цепочке вверх от вас до заказчика, чтобы оценить результат работы и, например, оценить, что было сделано не так, как предполагалось, и на каком этапе, то в этом процессе распределения ответственности аналитик уже участвовать не будет.:)

Как происходит процесс верификации результата работы?

Если задания спускаются сверху вниз, то верификация результата производится снизу вверх.

Результат работы программиста - это программа. Ее правильность сверяется с техническим заданием.

Результат работы аналитика - это техническое задание. Его правильность сверяется с требованиями заказчика.

Ну, а если требования заказчика сами по себе не корректны или неадекватны, то заказчику никого кроме себя винить не придется.:)

Answer (score 10):

А еще бывает себе полезно иногда задавать вопрос - "ЗАЧЕМ?". И этих зачем здесь достаточно.

Например, "Зачем мне сопротивляться составлению ТЗ...", - ведь я хочу получить этот опыт и двигаться в сторону аналитика/архитектора, тогда мягко оттирая текущего аналитика в сторону, выстраивай прямую коммуникацию с заказчиком, делай все лучшим образом и не забывай периодически освещать свою новую роль перед руководством.

Или например, зачем компании такой аналитик, тогда тоже делай все без него, а потом поставь вопрос "Зачем нам такой аналитик..." ребром перед начальством.

Или - "Зачем мне это все нужно...", - ведь тебе за это не платят и лучше уж тогда ничего не делать. Тогда, скорее всего, тебе пришло время искать новую работу. Ну и есть еще пару десятков разных зачем в этой, в целом типичной, ситуации.

Comment: Практически в любой ситуации «что и зачем я делаю?» — хороший вопрос. )

Comment: Я считаю, что программист должен делать свою работу- писать код. За это и платят. Если разработчик занимается написанием технического задания, то это уже размытие ролей. Опять же, в организации есть аналитик.

Answer (score 6):

Насколько я знаю, обычно это делается так:

1. (Бизнес-)аналитик собирает требования от заказчика.
2. (Бизнес-)аналитик пишет функциональную спецификацию для команды. В ней описано, как всё должно работать с точки зрения пользователя — то есть список фич. Функциональная спецификация может быть в формате use-case'ов или, если команда работает по Scrum, user-story.
3. Системный аналитик или техлид пишет техническую спецификацию. В ней описано, как всё должно быть реализовано внутри. Архитектура, технологии, стиль кодирования, используемые инструменты.
4. По технической спецификации работают программисты, тестировщики, системные администраторы, администраторы баз данных и прочая техническая братия.

В целом, написание техдокументации может как входить, так и не входить в ваши обязанности. Обычно, чем выше должность, тем чаще приходится все-таки что-то документировать. Если хотите отказаться, то можете аргументировать свою позицию тем, что не имеете должной квалификации и не можете гарантировать качества продукта.

Если всё-таки придется писать документацию, то это может быть только техническая. Убедитесь, что функциональная спецификация есть, что она полна, однозначна, непротиворечива. При обнаружении любых неточностей идите к аналитику и уточняйте заранее. Неточности — это баг спецификации.

Определите, кто является заказчиком документации, т.е. человеком, который оценивает её готовность и принимает работу. Скорее всего, это будет ваш аналитик. Сверяйте документ с ним, пока он не скажет, что его всё устраивает. Потом пусть ставит подпись, что документ принял. Обязательно подключите к процессу тестировщика, который будет с вами работать над этим проектом.